# overloading comparison operators in C++, how do I compare with const parameters?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I'm asked to overload a comparison operator for a structure.

```
friend bool operator< (const ObjectID& id1, const ObjectID& id2);
```

Do I need to consider to compare the cases where either id1 or id2 is `const`? How to implement then?

Comment: No, this function is all you'd need. You cannot have overloads of a function where the arguments differ only by `const` or it is ambiguous which to call.

Comment: @Cyber Actually you can have functions where the *reference* argument type differs only by `const`ness.

Comment: @Cyber [(example)](http://ideone.com/5DAmbq)

Comment: @Cyber It's not an ambiguity issue. If they differ only by top-level cv-qualifiers, they are the same function.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to consider the other cases, because in the case where the comparison gets passed non-const parameters the compiler will automatically add const for you to allow the single operator to match.